# how to send parameters in a popup window using JSP, Spring MVC, Hibernate

Tags: javascript, java, spring, hibernate, jsp

New to JSP and JavaScript but familiar with Spring MVC and Hibernate.
I am trying to insert values to database using a popup window after user clicks on the create button.
Steps:
1. User clicks the create button
2. a popup window opens with the text boxes to input values (like name, age)
3. two buttons with in the popup to save and cancel. Once save is clicked then it goes to the controller and save to DB. Cancel is to return back to the previous page.

Am able to do this with out popup window but i want it to work with the popup window. Thanks.

Code Snippet is Below....It doesnt bring show the popup window when i click the create button.

My Jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showPopupWindow() {
            document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'block';

        }
        </script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="showPopupWindow()">create</button>
<button class="sendBtn" onclick="closePopupWindow()">Cancel</button>
<div id="popupWindow">
 <form:form commandName="person" action="createP" method="post" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">name</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <form:input type="text" id ="name" path="name" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="age">age</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <form:input type="text" id ="age" path="age" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="submit" id ="buttonUpdate"  value="save" class="btn btn-default"/>
                                </div>
                            </div> 



                        </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: One option is using bootstrap as your css framework, go to this link to see some examples of modal windows and other ui controls: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your code your div is always shownup since your style on the div is not none

```
<div id="popupWindow" style="display:none;">
```

Why not using jquery instead of default javascript ?
It is already has dialog function which view your div as dialog

```
$("#popupWindow").dialog();
//After that you can send your form in an ajax request
$.ajax({
   url:url,
   data:$(form).serialize(),
   success:function(data) {
       //dosomething();
    }
});
```